# 3ware: Add a drive to a RAID unit

Tags: raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware RAID controller running a RAID-6.  I manage the RAID via the `tw_cli` command line utility.

So, one drive in the array failed, and I removed the faulty drive (`p6`) from the array, and then inserted a new drive.

For some reason, the 3ware controller placed the drive in an older, inoperable array (`u1`).  So I deleted that array.  I now want to add the new drive to the RAID-6, which is `u0`.

So I have:

```
# tw_cli /c0/u0 show

Unit     UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  VPort Stripe  Size(GB)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0       RAID-6    DEGRADED       -       -       -     256K    2793.91   
u0-0     DISK      OK             -       -       p0    -       465.651   
u0-1     DISK      OK             -       -       p1    -       465.651   
u0-2     DISK      OK             -       -       p2    -       465.651   
u0-3     DISK      OK             -       -       p3    -       465.651   
u0-4     DISK      OK             -       -       p4    -       465.651   
u0-5     DISK      OK             -       -       p5    -       465.651   
u0-6     DISK      DEGRADED       -       -       -     -       465.651   
u0-7     DISK      OK             -       -       p7    -       465.651   
u0/v0    Volume    -              -       -       -     -       10        
u0/v1    Volume    -              -       -       -     -       2783.91
```

As you can see, drive `p6` is not part of `u0`.  However, it *is* detected by the controller:

```
# tw_cli /c0 show

Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-6    DEGRADED       -       -       256K    2793.91   RiW    OFF    

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  0   -            ST3500630AS         
p1    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  1   -            ST3500630AS         
p2    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  2   -            ST3500630AS         
p3    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  3   -            ST3500320AS         
p4    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  4   -            ST3500630AS         
p5    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  5   -            ST3500630AS         
p6    OK             -    465.76 GB SATA  6   -            ST3500320AS         
p7    OK             u0   465.76 GB SATA  7   -            ST3500630AS         

Name  OnlineState  BBUReady  Status    Volt     Temp     Hours  LastCapTest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bbu   On           Yes       OK        OK       OK       0      xx-xxx-xxxx
```

So here we see that `p6` is detected by the controller, but it is not part of the unit `u0`.  So I just need to add it somehow.  Unfortunately, I cannot find the syntax to do this.

Looking through the [**tw_cli docs**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/tw_cli.8.html#primary_command_syntax), there doesn't seem to be a unit-level command to add a drive to a unit.  So, how do you add a drive to a unit?  How can I make `p6` part of `u0`?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I agree, it's vague. I've always worked with spares, so drives are added automatically. Perhaps you can hack that too:

```
tw_cli /c0 add raidtype=spare disk=6
```

Then perhaps it will pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this on my system with the following command:

```
tw_cli /c0/u0 start rebuild disk=6
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and as I was reading the `tw_cli` help screens to find the incantation, it actually changed the status on its own to add the changed p* disk to the u* unit, and start rebuilding the array. It's possible that the controller just has some small amount of back-off time in case you're taking time to seat the drive, and then it kicks into the logical course of action.